# do something if window.history location is from www.example.com

Tags: javascript, url, history

how can we determine if window.history is from a certain URL like www.example.com , and then do something for example :

`if ( //window.history includes example.com string ) {
$('.myclassname').hide()
}`

it actually needs to know the link location of history ... is there any way to find it out ?

Comment: Do you mean like a referer where a user came from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191778/use-get-server-variables-in-javascript-jquery-ajax May this helps =)

Comment: Then use      var ref = <?php $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know PHP :(

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the referer(the page user came from) via `document.referer`. You can't access history from js.

Comment: with document.referrer, how can we extract the URL of the previous page in which a user was ?

Comment: `alert(document.referrer)`

Comment: I tested that before, it alerts a blank popup while first I go to google.com and then go to my html link...

Comment: User should **click** the link to pass referer. If you visit google, then just paste link into address bar, referer will be empty. By the way, google uses anti-referer protection.

Comment: about google yeah u are right. but about the link, I have 2 html files, index.html & single.html. I've put single.html link in index.html. first i go to index and then click on the link of single page.. but still the alert is blank ...